# Show dialog only once, not after level restart

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my own dialog system which is basically a gameobject with a collider. After triggering collider, `Canvas` with a `Text` component should show up. So far, this works. Now, I want to make it happen only once. Here how its work: I start level trigger showing dialog. Game is pretty hardcore so player probably will die. When player dies, I call `Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);` (so basically I restart level)

If I use something like this in scrip with collider

```
 private static bool firstTimeText = true;

 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
 {
     if (coll.tag == "Player" && firstTimeText)
     {
         GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
         firstTimeText = false;
     }
 }
```

everything works like a charm. EXCEPT if I make copy of this gameobject, static variable in script will "handle" that every instantion of this object will have firstTimeText on false after trigger dialog first time. So basically I can use it only once.

So is there any sollution for making trigger which run only once and not reset after `Application.LoadLevel`?

Also this doesn't work

```
void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Note that `transform.gameObject` is unecessary from within a MonoBehaviour - you can refer directly to `gameObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are globally identical - therefore if you need to have multiple gameobjects exhibiting this behavior, they'll need to hook into different static values in some way.

One way to do this would be to have a key, and then keeping a static list of all "keys" already displayed. My recommendation would be a [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) - thus

```
private static HashSet<string> firstTimeSet = new HashSet<string>();

public string singleRunKey;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    if (coll.tag == "Player"
        && firstTimeSet.Add(singleRunKey))
    { GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false; }
}
```

Note that [`.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `true` if the item wasn't in the collection (and adds it), but `false` if it already was (and does not add it, because no duplicates). All you have to do now is assign `singleRunKey` a unique value per object via the Inspector, and each one will run exactly once

Answer (score 1):

Consider just having a static class that will set a flag to indicate if the dialog should appear or not.  Note that I am not inheriting from MonoBehaviour here.

```
public static class ApplicationData {
    public static bool ShowDialog = true;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (ApplicationData.ShowDialog)
{
    ShowDialog();
    ApplicationData.ShowDialog = false;
}
```

The static class will retain its values during the lifetime of your application.  So, it will retain the FALSE value even if you reload your scene.

Comment: huh interesting idea... im going to try it now